# How to find a specific word in string with Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I got a few string like so:

```
TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_widesky_light_87689uiyhk
```

AND

```
TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_sky_light_87689uiyhk
```

AND

```
TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_widesky_dark_87689uiyhk
```

AND

```
TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_sky_dark_87689uiyhk
```

I need to check whether the strings above has one of the `widesky_light`, `sky_light`, `widesky_dark` and `sky_dark` with exactitude so I wrote this:

```
if my_string.match("widesky_light")
  ...
end
```

For each variant, but the problem I'm having is because `sky_light` and `widesky_light` are similar, my code is not working properly. I believe the solution to the above would be a regex, but I've spend the afternoon yesterday trying to get it to work without much success.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

A caveat: in this string (as example): `TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_widesky_light_87689uiyhk`, the part after `widesky_light`, which is `_87689uiyhk` is optional, meaning that sometimes I have it, sometimes I don't, so a solution would not be able to count on `_string_`.

Comment: Maybe you need `if my_string =~ /(?<=\b|_)(?:wide)?sky_(light|dark)(?=_|\b)/`?

Comment: Just add the delimiters: `if my_string.include?('_sky_light_')`

Comment: To match `sky_light` and not `widesky_light`: `/(?<!wide)sky_light/`.

Comment: Updated example for your caveat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Regex

### 1st regex : extract word for further checking

Here's a regex which only matches the interesting part :

```
(?<=_)[a-z_]+(?=(?:_|\b))
```

It means `lowercase word with possible underscore inside, between 2 underscores or after 1 underscore and before a word boundary`.
If you need some logic depending on the case (widesky, sky, light or dark), you could use this solution.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/lapikf/2) in action.

### 2nd regex : direct check if one of 4 words is present

If you just want to know if any of the 4 cases is present :

```
(?<=_)(?:wide)?sky_(?:dark|light)(?=(?:_|\b))
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/KPLEK4/2) in action, with either `_something_after` or nothing.

## Case statement

```
list = %w(
  TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_widesky_light_87689uiyhk
  TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_sky_light_87689uiyhk
  TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_widesky_dark_87689uiyhk
  TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_sky_dark_87689uiyhk
  TFjyg9780878_867978-DGB097908-78679iuhi698_trash_dark_87689uiyhk
)

list.each do |string|
  case string
  when /widesky_light/ then puts "widesky light found!"
  when /sky_light/     then puts "sky light found!"
  when /widesky_dark/  then puts "widesky dark found!"
  when /sky_dark/      then puts "sky dark found!"
  else                      puts "Nothing found!"
  end
end
```

In this order, the case statement should be fine. `widesky_dark` won't match twice, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just need to reorder your `if` statements

```
if my_string.match(/widesky_light/)
  return 'something'
end
if my_string.match(/sky_light/)
  return 'something'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
case my_string
when /_(sky_light)/
  # just sky_light
when /sky_light/
  # widesky_light
when /_(sky_dark)/
  # just sky_dark
when /sky_dark/
  # widesky_dark
else
  puts "I don't like"
end
```